# Rails tutorial chapter3 heroku cannot find controller StaticPagesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a page doesn't exist problem with my sample_app from the tutorial. I just followed all the steps and my code looks like this:

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'static_pages/home'

  get 'static_pages/help'

  get 'static_pages/about'

  get 'static_pages/contact'
end
```

Controller - the file name is static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

On GET "/" i'm getting

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant StaticPagesController)
```

It looks like it cannot find my controller.

Thanks for any help
Andrej

Comment: The code in routes.rb and the controller work.

Comment: I just followed the exact steps in chapter 3 of the tutorial.

Comment: is `static_pages_controller.rb` living at `app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb`? file name and path are very important and it won't work unless it's exactly that.

Comment: @JoshBrody yes btw. i used rails generate to create the controller

Comment: is your code on github somewhere?

Comment: @JoshBrody https://github.com/hucKOder/sample_app

Comment: I'm not seeing your other controller. Can you make sure your code is up to date? `git add .; git commit -m "update"; git push origin master`

Comment: Thanks; I pulled down your application and it ran as expected. Are you still experiencing the error locally?

Comment: Unfortunately something happened when merging with other branch. Really don't know what it was. But now i updated git and now it works thanks for help. :)