# Consistent problems with rails and Hartl’s tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to develop a web app for about a month now. I'm relatively new to web dev but I've been able to develop a pretty intuitive understanding of Rails since the beginning. However, I have run into many problems with the framework that seems to be unsolvable. Currently, I'm receiving a

> [Routing Error: uninitialized constant StaticPagesController]

when running the site on my local server. I've followed the Hartl tut to a T(my files look exactly the same), and yet I'm running into these problems.

If some one could please tell me the optimal tech spec for running Rails on a MacBook Air, MacOS high Sierra 10.13.2

Comment: Bizarrely, a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246304/rails-tutorial-chapter3-heroku-cannot-find-controller-staticpagescontroller

Comment: Can you put your code up on github somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: my code looks exactly like the user's you linked in your previous comment

Comment: Are you having the same issue he was then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246304/rails-tutorial-chapter3-heroku-cannot-find-controller-staticpagescontroller#comment83475496_48246304

Comment: yeah exactly the same. I also run into a host of other problems when running my tests. In my initial run through of the book I got up to ch 12 using a Toshiba machine before I started experiencing mass failure of my app. Rails began to identify errors that were not there. Now, I've purchased a MacBook Air because I had the framework runs better on these machines, yet I still have the same problems. But to answer your question, yes, the repo is at git@github.com:iThompkins/sample_app.git

Comment: Your code isn't exactly the same :) You need to make sure you're following the correct case, and making sure you're using underscores. These small details are what make Rails Rails. I would recommend going through the same chapter and making sure your filenames match as well as the contents inside those files :)

Comment: Josh, you're a homie! Which chapter should I start from? And also can you identify these errors. I ask this not because I'm going to ignore your advice, but so I know what sort of errors I'm prone to making? thanks again boss

Comment: Chapter 3 I believe.

app/controllers/staticpages_controller.rb should be static_pages_controller.rb, and inside that file it should read `class StaticPagesController`, not `class StaticpagesController` 

More on this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Comment: Thanks, also-- have you ran any tests with my code? I'm receiving errors in that as well, but I suspect they're from a similar issure

Comment: You're welcome! I haven't, no; I'm admittedly mobile right now far and away from anything that runs Ruby. I would suspect that following these conventions and small details closely will solve many of your issues :)

Comment: Okay one more question I promise. Before reading your response I had suspected it was an issue with my machine, but now I see it's just a lack of attention to detail. However, I recently pull Michael Hartl's git for the complete sample app, and still couldn't run it on my machine. Any thoughts?

Comment: No idea without knowing the error you're experiencing and where you're experiencing it. I've never gone through the tutorial myself.

Comment: @iThompkins, you need to post the code for your `StaticPagesController`

Comment: **Start with paying any respect to the author of the tutorial that helps you and type his name properly.**

Comment: Is his name not michael hartl?